# Interstitials showing outside app

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services, interstitial

I´ve interstitials on my app that appears after a minute a person click the play button. To that part is ok.

The problem is that if the person clicks play and inmediately goes to other app or check emails or whatever, when the minute lapse happens the interstitial pops anywhere.

Which is the perfect way to show the interstitials only caged inside my app?

This is my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4763920058070972/3862555444");


AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And this is where I activate the interstitial after clicking play button:

```
    public void onClickPlayButton(View view) {
    radioService.play();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }, 60000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem is you don't guarantee that the user will stay in use of your app the whole minute that's why the ad showing after closing the app !!

- the user should know which app the Ad is coming from ,
- you should put the ad when the user is expecting a pause,
- not interrupt an activity ,

Comment: where should I set the OnPause function? At the playbutton or above when the adunitid is loaded?

Comment: This answer does not even attempt to demonstrate a "_way to show the interstitials only caged inside my app_"

Comment: I posted a partial solution above but now ads are not created onResume :/